# please help me to install ubuntu18.04 on epson AT997 pc

Tags: 18.04

please help me to install ubuntu18.04 on epson AT997 (when i was try to install ubuntu os on AT997 pc got this error "reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key",  even i was set UEFI to disable, security boot to disable    )

Comment: It's not clear to me which steps you've performed and what problem you are having. Did you verify your ISO prior to write to media? https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 did you write to media? and verify that write? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck or is your issue later than that?  Are you trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server?  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop? or which specific ISO are you using?  (GA or HWE stack? or 18.04, 18.04.1 ... 18.04.5 like detail).

Comment: The message you've provided reads to me like you've failed in the first two steps & you can't boot the media in which to install (see prior links), but it's unclear, as your tagging of `grub` may imply a failure of `grub-installer` but you'll get a different messages during install for that which you haven't mentioned.  Please clarify.

Comment: thank you for your reply, yes i verified that "ubuntu-ja-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso" i could installed from the same OS cd  in other pc epson AT992 & AT994 models  , but only couldn't install on AT997 ,as well as i test on two different AT997 pc even both are new pc.

Comment: sorry! i made mistake while tagging. this is my first experience participate here ,when i try  install ubuntu18.04 OS in bios legacy mode could not. i just got this error "reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key"